# angular 2 ngif not working on ios devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, angular

I have a service which fetches data from the server on startup. This is working fine. The data gets populated into an array. When the array is filled, I check if the length is greater 0. If so another view gets displayed.. 
This is working fine on windows / android devices. 
As soon as I use apple safari on my mac (with chrome its working), iPad or iPhone the view is not changing. Even with using chrome on iPad or iPhone.

Heres the template

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" *ngIf="imageCount === 0">
      <p class="text-center">sorry mate.. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" *ngIf="imageCount !== 0">
      <div class="center-image">
        <p class="text-center">some other great code.. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Did you lead the required polyfills https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html

Comment: yes. I'm using the latest seed by mgechev.